# insert an image beside text in listview

Tags: android, android-studio

hey how can i insert an image into the listview?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] AndroidVer={"Alpha", "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean", "Kitkat",
            "Lollipop", "Marshmallow", "Nougat", "Oreo", "Pie", "Android 10", "Android 11"};
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AndroidVer));
}
```

}

Comment: Try a recycler view.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/1560485-android-recyclerview-tutorial-with-kotlin. You can add images with a list adapter, but you'll need to create a custom viewholder.  Why not do that with RecyclerView?

Comment: how do i do that? sorry for asking that as i am just starting on android studio

Comment: Follow the example in the link provided.